# Python magicmock causes 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unregister'

Tags: python, python-2.7, magicmock

I'm trying to patch a function call with a custom mock I wrote

```
    subscriberMock = MagicMock(side_effect=subscriber)
    subscriberMock.return_value.unregister.return_value = True
    with patch('rospy.Subscriber', subscriberMock):
        data['op'] = "unsubscribe"
        data['topic'] = "/helo"
        self.rosbridge.incoming(data)
```

The inner method has this piece of code

```
self.subscribers[topic] = rospy.Subscriber(topic, 'msg', outgoing_function)
self.subscribers[topic].unregister() # <-- AttributeError
```

However when I run this it returns an attribute error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unregister'

I'm guessing the `return_value` is set to a NoneType but I thought this `subscriberMock.return_value.unregister.return_value` would override it

---

More Information:

if I print `self.subscribers[topic]` it returns `None`. It then runs the side effect. Why should `self.subscribers[topic] = None` given that I have a return value for a parameter in it.

Comment: What is the output of `self.subscribers[topic]` when you print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the above mock, you have to write a Mock calling the instantiation within the side effect

```
    def subscriber (topic, topic_type, outgoing_function):
        # convert to a ROS object
        output = ROSBridgeObject()
        output.foo = topic
        # pretend we got a message from what we subscribed to
        outgoing_function(output)
        mock = MagicMock()
        subscriberMock.unregister.return_value = True
        return mock
    subscriberMock = MagicMock(side_effect=subscriber)
```

This is because MagicMock's either have return values or side effects